# Why does my SciKit linear regression perform more poorly (lower R-squared) when I add an independent variable?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics, linear-regression

I am trying to perform linear regression to predict an outcome y based on about ten independent variables X. I have 125 data points with data for y and each of X.

```
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
    from sklearn import metrics

    X_array = X.values.reshape(-1,X.shape[1]) #converting dataframe into          array
    #125 x 9
    y_array = y.values.reshape(-1,1)
    #125 x 1
    #Split data
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_array, y_array,          test_size=0.2, random_state=100)
    #define linear regression and fit to the data
    regressor = LinearRegression()  
    regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
    r_sqr = regressor.score(X_test,y_test,sample_weight=None)
```

The problem is that when I run this code for just one variable within X (0.52), I get a better R-squared score than when I run it for all of X (0.33). **How can this be? Shouldn't I get better performance of the model with more independent variables?**

I've tried r2_score function and tried running train_test_split on the data in data frame for instead of array, but no changes.

Comment: Your model might be over-fitting when trained on more variables, leading to a lower score on the test set. You could try to verify your expectation by scoring the training set instead. If the answer is not so simple, please update the code in the question to completely reproduce the behavior (generate example data and explicitly run both cases).